# Java Check wether Beginning and End Dates are within interval

Tags: java, sql, date, intervals

I have to check wether the Beginning and End date of a Booking is between a timespan chosen by a User. So if a User says that he wants to see all bookings from feb 12 to feb 15, it should only show the bookings that are within this timespan. I just cant figure it out, I hope someone can help. This is my attempt so far:

```
    Timestamp tsBeginning = new Timestamp(dateBeginning.getTime()); //date entered by user
    Timestamp tsEnd = new Timestamp(dateEnd.getTime()); //date entered by user

for (Booking b : bookingList) {
                if(((b.getBeginning().after(tsBeginning) || b.getBeginning().equals(tsBeginning)) && b.getBeginning().before(tsEnd) || b.getBeginning().equals(tsEnd)) 
                        && ((b.getEnd().after(tsEnd) || b.getEnd().equals(tsEnd)) && (b.getEnd().before(tsEnd) || b.getEnd().equals(tsEnd)))){
                    bookingsForRoomInPeriod.add(b);
```

Comment: If a booking overlaps the border, you probably want to include it, is that right? The user chooses from Feb 12 at 15:00 to Feb 15 at 21:00 and there is a booking on Feb 12 from 14 to 16 — should it be included?

Comment: If you're using sql, you should just use a database query to filter for those date ranges

Comment: Once you start mixing `&&` and `||` without grouping them with parenthesis, I think the chance of error is high.  You might want to clarify what order you expect these to execute with some parenthesis.

Comment: Also, I would break that huge `if` statement down, make some easier to read helper methods that do some checks for you (like if a date is withing two other dates) so that the whole thing becomes easier to read.  I think order of operations (parenthesis) and the long list of logical operators is messing you up.

Comment: @cricket_007 what would the query need to look like? I'd like to include bookings that only happen within one day to show up as well (for example from 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-01). I tried this: SELECT * from HA2_BOOKINGS WHERE beginning >= '14-JUN-18' AND beginning <= '14-JUN-18' AND end >= '14-JUN-18' and end <= '14-JUN-18' ; within the database to test around but it didnt show the booking from jun 14th.

Comment: I generally find that this kind of thing looks best if I write `if(...) { /* before */ } else if (...) { /* after */ } else { /* in range */ }` . Try it that way, you may find the logic easier to read. If add new member functions, so you can write `if(!booking.endsBefore(...) && !booking.startsAfter(...)){...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** It’s taken a long discussion. I finally seem to understand: A booking begins and ends on a date and an hour of day (like 14th June 3:30 PM). The user enters a start date and an end date, but no hours. You need to include bookings that are completely contained in the date range *inclusive*. That is, between 00:00 on the start date and 24:00 on the end date.

```
      LocalDate userBeginning = // …
      LocalDate userEnd = // …
      LocalDateTime userBeginningTime = userBeginning.atStartOfDay();
      LocalDateTime userEndTime = userEnd.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay();

      if (! b.getBeginning().isBefore(userBeginningTime)
                && ! b.getEnd().isAfter(userEndTime)) {
          bookingsForRoomInPeriod.add(b);
      }
```

I am assuming that `getBeginning` and `getEnd` return `LocalDateTime`. In Java “the end of the day” (midnight) is represented as 00:00 the next day, which is why I add 1 day to the end date that the user has entered.

The `Timestamp` class that you seem to be using is long outdated. `java.time` is the modern Java date and time API and much nicer to work with than the old-fashioned date and time classes. The date and time classes in `java.sql` in particular have an ugly design that halfway tries to hide that they are subclasses of the (also poorly designed) `java.util.Date`.

Assuming you picked `Timestamp` because you get the time from your database, and assuming that you can use at least Java 8 and at least JDBC 4.2, get `LocalDateTime` objects directly from your result set using one of the `ResultSet.getObject` methods passing `LocalDateTime.class` as the type you want.

**Previous version of answer:**

> …only the date matters not the time, and only bookings that are
>   completely within the selected timestamps of the user should be
>   included

```
      if (! b.getBeginning().before(tsBeginning) && ! b.getEnd().after(tsEnd)) {
           bookingsForRoomInPeriod.add(b);
      }
```

I am using “not before” as a short way to require “on or after”. Similarly I am using “not after” to express “before or on”.

That said, the `Timestamp` class that you seem to be using is long outdated and also ill suited for dates without time of day. Use a database datatype without time of day (in most RDBMS it’s simply called `date`) and use `LocalDate` from `java.time` in Java instead. `java.time` is the modern Java date and time API and much nicer to work with than the old-fashioned date and time classes. The date and time classes in `java.sql` in particular have an ugly design that halfway tries to hide that they are subclasses of the (also poorly designed) `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Yes I'm using timestamp because I get my time for my bookings from a database, I tried your code but now it's also including dates that star before userBegninning and end after UserEnd (for example Beginning of Booking 2018-06-08 and End 2018-06-22) , but bookings that only last one day arent included at all for some reason

Comment: In that case you have not explained your desired result clearly enough. Are bookings from and to dates, or do hours matter? Should only bookings that are completely within the user selected timestamp be included? Please edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: Yes, only the date matters not the time and only bookings that are compleatly within the selected timestamps of the user should be included, sorry english isn't my nativer language so its sometimes hard to tell someone what I want to do :D

Comment: Everything works now, but bookings at only last one day are still not included so if the user says from 2018-06-15 to 2018-06-15 the date still doesnt show up

Comment: Can a booking begin and end on the same date? Zero nights? Sounds like some off-by-one error in my understanding of your requirements.

Comment: It's supposed to be a Booking of a Room for a Meeting for example, so if the meeting lasts 2 hours it's supposed to show up but I always need to add one day for it to work so if the booking lasts from the 14th to the 14 i need the user needs to choose from the 14th to the 15th as begnning and end, I think this is caused because of my timestamps. It thinks that the 14th at 3pm is > than the 14th and not =.

Comment: So if I use **"SELECT * from HA2_BOOKINGS WHERE BEGINNING >='14-JUN-2018' AND END <='14-JUN-2018';"** in my SQL theres no result but when I use **"SELECT * from HA2_BOOKINGS WHERE 
 BEGINNING >='14-JUN-2018' AND END <='15-JUN-2018';"** it works and the booking thats only on the 14th shows up. Is there any way around this?